# Django Inline for m2m field

Tags: python, django

I've a Page model with m2m field to model called content
I created an inline page but when testing the performance with django silk, I saw 11 queries mostly because of language field that's being fetched at least 4 times
here's my code:

models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.ManyToManyField('content.Content', blank=True, related_name="as_page_names_set")
    description = models.ManyToManyField('content.Content', blank=True, related_name="as_page_description_set")
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Language(models.Model):
    language_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    iso_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True)

class Content(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, models.CASCADE)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(max_length=2048)
```

admin:

```
class PageNameAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    extra = 1
    model = Page.name.through
    verbose_name = "Page Name"
    form = PageContentForm
    

class PageDescriptionAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    extra = 1
    model = Page.description.through
    form = PageContentForm
    verbose_name = "Page Description"


@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PageNameAdmin]
    exclude = ('name', 'description')
    
    def get_queryset(self, request: HttpRequest) -> QuerySet[Any]:
        return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('name', 'description')
```

forms.py:

```
class PageContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all(), required=True)
    content = RichTextFormField(required=True)

    FIELDS = ['content', 'language']

    class Meta:
        model = Page.name.through
        fields = ('page', 'content', 'language')
    
    def get_initial_for_field(self, field: Field, field_name: str) -> Any:
        if self.instance.pk and field_name in self.FIELDS:
            return getattr(self.instance.content, field_name)
        return super().get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)
        
    def clean(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        if self.instance.pk is None:
            self.cleaned_data['content'] = self.create_content_obj(**self.cleaned_data)
            self.cleaned_data.pop('language')
        else:
            self.cleaned_data['content'] = self.get_content_obj(**self.cleaned_data)
        return super().clean()
    
    def create_content_obj(self, content = None, language = None, *args, **kwargs):
        return Content.objects.create(content=content, language=language)
    
    def get_content_obj(self, *args, **kwargs):
        content_obj = self.instance.content
        for k in self.FIELDS:
            setattr(content_obj, k, kwargs[k])
        content_obj.save()
        return content_obj
```

What am I doing wrong?